# Can all costumes be aquired for free (no tower bux)?

Tags: tiny-tower

I have noticed that randomly I will sometimes have a citizen move in that is wearing a costume.  After looking at the costume list it appears to me that these are "buyable" costumes using tower bux.  This made me wonder - is it possible to get all of these costumes by random move ins, or are some "buy only".  I'd rather save my bux for "buy only".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From personal experience, even if a bitizen moves in with a costume you haven't bought yet, it won't be unlocked for other bitizens unless you buy it with tower bux.

Comment: An important distinction, and +1 for that. I'm less interested in "unlocking" the costumes for multi-bitizen use. Instead I'd rather have one of each. The reason being to make them quick to find at a glance when doing the "find bitizen X" challenge.

Comment: I think waiting for this to happen by chance is futile. The appearance of a specially costumed is rare, you'd have to multiply that by the chance the bitizen will land on residential floor, that the floor has a vacant spot AND that the costume is oen you haven't seen before. You'd rather spend your time picking one of the free looks for you bitizens and just make sure each floor has a similar getup, this way you'd know for example, that all your blue bitizens work at the record shop.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you are right.  I guess for costumes I do buy I can put everyone on that floor in it as well.  I hadn't thought of that.  I was thinking more of finding "the one" rather than a more sophisticated search.  It gives me the crazy idea of rainbow sorting them from bottom to top too.  Now I have work to do.... :)

Answer (score 0):

The bitizen who moved in is the only one with the costume.

The costume will not be unlocked.  When you do an outfit change, the costume will disappear, just like regular... except you can't get it back without "re" buying it.

I speak from experience of when a gangster moved in<strike>to my apartment</strike>.